# Creating a 10x10 field of pushButtons

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

Hey I want to create a 8x8 field of pushButtons. When using this Code

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QVector>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout();
ui->centralwidget->setLayout(layout);

QVector<QVector<QPushButton*>> buttons2DVector(8);

for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
    buttons2DVector[i].resize(8);

    for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
        QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("button");
        layout->addWidget(b,i,j);
        buttons2DVector[i][j] = b;
    }
}
```

the error is:
unknown type Name "QGridLayout"
unknown type Name "ui"

the Code was given to me but I dont know how to use it properly. As you can probably see I am a beginner in QT and C++ but it would be nice if someone could help me.

Comment: You can't have code outside your function: `QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout();
ui->centralwidget->setLayout(layout);`

Comment: If you're defining your layout programmatically you don't need the `ui` parts, and instead should add widgets to your main window in its constructor. Perhaps you should walk through [the getting started tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-tutorials-notepad-example.html) to see how it all works.

Comment: Where do I have to put my Code then?
If I would do it with the Widgets, would I have to place every single pushButton?

Comment: You can create a function in your MainWindow class. However you should listen to the advice from @Botje.

Comment: and what function should I create?

Comment: @ejoty You can mix and match: design the grid and everything else in a `ui` file, then add buttons to the gridlayout in the constructor. If your window is _only_ the gridlayout, just do it all in code.

Comment: ***and what function should I create?*** You can name a function yourself. It's probably a void function taking no arguments.

Comment: Okay I tried the void function but it says know "expected unqualified-id".
I am probably using the function in a wrong way. Could you Maybe modify my Code so it would work?

Comment: Only if its not too much work of course

Comment: I dont know what that means @Adrian Mole. Do you mean thta my title says 10x10 and later I wrote 8x8? The number does more or less not metter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you added the following to your `MainWindow` class declaration:

```
QVector<QVector<QPushButton*>> buttons2DVector(8);
void createGrid();
```

You could create the grid programmatically as follows:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QVector>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    createGrid();
}

void MainWindow::createGrid() {
    QFrame *frame = new QFrame(this);
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(frame);

    for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
        buttons2DVector[i].resize(8);

        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            QPushButton *b = new QPushButton("button", layout);
            layout->addWidget(b,i,j);
            buttons2DVector[i][j] = b;
        }
    }

    setCentralWidget(frame);
}
```

Comment: How do I add anything to my Mainwindow class declaration or where do I find it? Is it still in the mainwondow.cpp ?
Sry for the Basic question

Comment: That would be the header file (mainwindow.h) suggest reading a c++ tutorial or primer if you're new to this.